# Kotlin: Combined case statements, disallow to access to member variable

Tags: kotlin

In my `when` statement, we have 3 cases that is performing the similar thing.

```
private fun bindValue(target: Activity) {
    val declaredFields = target::class.java.declaredFields

    for (field in declaredFields) {
        for (annotation in field.annotations) {

            when(annotation) {
                is ReflectSource -> {
                    field.isAccessible = true
                    field.set(target, annotation.value)
                }
                is ReflectBinary -> {
                    field.isAccessible = true
                    field.set(target, annotation.value)
                }
                is ReflectRuntime -> {
                    field.isAccessible = true
                    field.set(target, annotation.value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I thought of merging them, as below

```
private fun bindValue(target: Activity) {
    val declaredFields = target::class.java.declaredFields

    for (field in declaredFields) {
        for (annotation in field.annotations) {

            when(annotation) {
                is ReflectSource, is ReflectBinary, is ReflectRuntime -> {
                    field.isAccessible = true
                    field.set(target, annotation.value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, it errors out stating that the `value` of `annotation` is not accessible. Why? Can't I combine those 3 case statements?

**Update**
My three classes as below

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD)
annotation class ReflectSource(val value: Int)

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD)
annotation class ReflectBinary(val value: Int)

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD)
annotation class ReflectRuntime(val value: Int)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can't I combine those 3 case statements?

No, you can't. Remember how it works in

```
is ReflectSource -> {
    field.isAccessible = true
    field.set(target, annotation.value)
}
```

case: `annotation.value` hides a cast inserted by the compiler, it's really `(annotation as ReflectSource).value`.

Which class should the compiler insert cast to when you use `is ReflectSource, is ReflectBinary, is ReflectRuntime`?

In principle the compiler could handle this, but it would complicate the language description and the implementation for a quite rare case.

One option to reduce duplication would be

```
val value = when(annotation) {
    is ReflectSource -> annotation.value
    is ReflectBinary -> annotation.value
    is ReflectRuntime -> annotation.value
    else -> null
}
value?.let {
    field.isAccessible = true
    field.set(target, it)
}
```